# Where are the articles?

Tags: grammar, articles

Here is a sentence from NASA News:

"As material falls toward this black hole it is dragged into orbit as part of an accretion disk"

can somebody please explain why it is not:

"As material falls toward this black hole it is dragged into **THE** orbit as **A** part of **THE** accretion disk"

since 1) we exactly know what orbit we are talking about, 2) the material becomes ONE of the parts of the accretion disk, and 3) we know exactly what black hole we are talking and it has only one accretion disk

Thank you

Comment: The partial sentence refers to _all_ galaxies with an active galactic nucleus. It does not refer to ESO 021-G004 only. https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/goddard/2019/hubble-views-a-galaxy-with-an-active-center

Comment: (1) The strings 'in orbit' and 'into orbit' are anarthrous set phrases. (2) Although 'a part' would do, 'part' is better as the material is non-discrete (notionally, at least). Again, 'part of' is idiomatic: "You are part of the team now." (3) 'The' would be the only choice had the accretion disk been mentioned before. But one often assumes a level of ignorance among the members of an audience ("... You may not previously have known that black holes have accretion disks, dear listener, but you do now ... you are intelligent enough to work out what the term means").

Comment: @Weoathtocreation definitely not as there is "this": "As material falls toward __this__ black hole.."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**"Into orbit"**

There are many possible orbits around an astronomical body, so "the orbit" is incorrect unless you have already specified which orbit you are talking about. "An orbit" would be grammatically correct, but "In orbit" has become idiomatic to describe being in a state of orbiting around something and so is often used.

"Part of" is also idiomatic where "part" is used like "some of" or "all of". "A part of" is also grammatically correct.

"The accretion disk" would be used only if it had been mentioned before ( or if only one could exist in the circumstances and it was universally understood to exist).

Comment: 1) yes, indeed, this is my mistake; 2) thanks, I see; 3) but isn't it the case here: " if only one could exist in the circumstances and it was universally understood to exist"?